# Cisco router help! No internet and only can ping one way

Tags: cisco, routing, router, internet

Here is the setup I have 2 networks.

1st one (this one is our old one and it is working great.)

ip address 10.22.227.X

subnet mask 255.255.255.0

DFG 10.22.227.254

2nd one (this is our new network that is not working right)

ip address 10.22.226.X

subnet mask 255.255.255.0

DFG 10.22.226.254

I can ping 10.22.227.131 from the 226 network but i can not ping 10.22.226.66 from the 227 network. (226.66 is my laptop 227.131 is my pc)
I can see the files on the 227 computer seams as thought i have directional network.... I also have no internet on the 226 network.

Here is the running config file from the router that connects the 226 and the 227 network together.

```
Router#show running-conf
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 894 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$ngyI$dZN2sb5gHUYC2A37wLRQM1
enable password united2315
!
no aaa new-model
!
resource policy
!
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description 0/0 10.22.227.254
 ip address 10.22.227.253 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description 0/1 10.22.226.254
 ip address 10.22.226.254 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
no ip classless
ip route 10.22.226.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.254
ip route 10.22.227.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.254
!
no ip http server
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0
 password cisco
 login
line vty 1 4
 login
!
end
```

The 227 network is managed by another company  they have provided me with this info.....

```
ip route 8.8.4.4 255.255.255.255 10.22.227.253 name TEST-TO-CLIENT-ROUTER       <=-- Added a test route 
ip route 10.22.226.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.253 name CLIENT-NETWORK          <=-- Added a route to the clients device 
s1.pryor#
s1.pryor#ping 10.22.227.253 <=-- I can Ping to the Clients device 

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.22.227.253, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/4/9 ms
s1.pryor#
s1.pryor#sho ip arp 10.22.227.253
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.22.227.253           1   0023.33e8.5c96  ARPA   Vlan1                                     <=-- Got an ARP and MAC address for the Clients device 
s1.pryor#


s1.pryor#ping 8.8.4.4 <=-- Can not ping pass the Clients Device 

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.4.4, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
s1.pryor-chv.robertsautoctr

================================
The routes in place I was able to Ping to the clients device but not pass it 
They will re-configure their router and call us back
Our routes in place
```

What am i doing wrong that i dont have internet and local network?
they told me they have routed the internet over to our 226 network all ready as well...

See screen shot for network setup[image: See network setup here]

Comment: Your picture shows the router with the '10.22.226.254' address, but the config shows .253?  Also could you confirm where the Internet is in this picture and what the IP of that device is?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

These configured routes should be removed from your configuration since they are directly connected:

```
ip route 10.22.226.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.254
ip route 10.22.227.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.254
```

Also you do not have a default route configured, so you probably need this:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.22.227.254
```

In regards to the other company's testing, since the PC's are using 10.22.227.254 as their gateway, the 'test' route pointing 8.8.4.4 is pointless, if it works it only proves that your router is hairpinning traffic back to its default next-hop.  A better test would be to 10.22.226.254.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Windows is not pingable by default.  Disable Windows Firewall (or add an ICMP Echo rule) and try again.

Comment: The 10.22.227.253 address is configured on the Cisco device, hopefully it doesn't have Windows Firewall enabled.

Comment: "I can ping 10.22.227.131 from the 226 network but i can not ping 10.22.226.66 from the 227 network. (226.66 is my laptop 227.131 is my pc)"

Comment: Ah whoops... i was looking at the testing from the other company, not the blurb at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping one way but not the other. In my experience it has always been a firewall somewhere. Check software firewalls on device, or maybe investigate a firewall you don't know about yet.